# Не могу растянуть span внутри td на всю высоту

Tags: html, css

```css
.darkbut{
  background-color: #808080;
  color: white;
  font-size:9pt;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left:20pt; padding-right: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:none; padding:0; margin:0">
      <input type="text">     
      <span class="darkbut" style="height: 14pt; padding: 0; margin:0;">Обновить цену</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

почему то сверху и снизу остаются отступы

Comment: Ответил в другом вашем вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437664/184648

Comment: старайтесь не использовать инлайн код в тэгах (атрибут style  тэгов).   Пока вы учитесь, это может и кажется вам  удобным, но это вызывает массу проблем при построении более серьезных проектов...   Профессионалы выносят подобные конструкции полностью в CSS блоки (или чаще в отдельные файлы .css)
@Qwertiy написал вам отличный пример,как надо делать.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Помогите спозиционировать input и div внутри td](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437627/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-input-%d0%b8-div-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-td)

Answer (score 1):

```css
td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px silver;
  line-height: 18px;
}

span{
  background-color: #808080;
  color: white;
  font-size: 9pt;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20pt;
  padding-right: 20pt;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
      <span>Обновить цену</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо, за изящное решение

Answer (score 0):

Установки в стилях для span:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: все равно огромный отступ от верхней границы ячейки

Comment: добавьте vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 0):

- Если известны размеры, то можно их явно указать, либо использоваьт `position:absolute`.
- Если неизвестны, то есть вариатн использовать flexbox вместо таблицы.