# Помогите спозиционировать input и div внутри td

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  .darkbut{
  background-color: #808080;
  color: white;
  font-size:9pt;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left:20pt; padding-right: 20pt;
  }
```

Comment: в следующие раз вставляйте html код тоже текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Старайтесь не использовать инлайн код в тэгах (атрибут style тэгов). Пока вы учитесь, это может и кажется вам удобным, но это вызывает массу проблем при построении более серьезных проектов... Профессионалы выносят подобные конструкции полностью в CSS блоки (или чаще в отдельные файлы .css) @toxxxa написал вам отличный пример,как надо делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
input {
  height: 22px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}
.darkbut {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  line-height: 26px;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: white;
  font-size:9pt;
  padding: 0 10pt; 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text">
    <span class="darkbut">Обновить цену</span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

А в два столбца есть возможность сделать?

Еще вариант input'у выставить float:left;

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотрите: Вам нужно сначала стилизировать **input[type=text]**, а потом уже **span**.

CSS:

```
/* .table_class - клас таблицы(если есть); 
   n - номер нужного td 
*/

        .table_class td:nth-child(n) {
             overflow:hidden;
        }
        .table_class td:nth-child(n) input[type="text"] {
             width:65%; /* примерно */
             floal:left;
        }
        .table_class .darkbut {
             float: right;
             display: block;
             line-height: 26px;
             background-color: #808080;
             color: white;
             font-size:9pt;
             text-align:center;
             width:35%;
    }
```